# Cannot get fastMM4 working with C++ Builder XE7 projects

Tags: c++builder, fastmm

I have tried to make fastMM4 work with C++ Builder XE7 applications, but I have not succeeded.

Just to test fastMM4 I created a very simple vcl-application where I intentionally created a memory leakage. I then followed the instructions given in `FastMM4BCB.cpp`.
First, I got problems when compiling `FastMM4BCB.cpp`:

```
[bcc64 Error] FastMM4BCB.cpp(2024): 
assigning to 'GetMemFunc' (aka 'void *(*)(int) __attribute__((fastcall))') 
from incompatible type 'void *(*)(NativeInt) __attribute__((fastcall))': 
type mismatch at 1st parameter ('int' vs 'NativeInt' (aka 'long long'))

[bcc64 Error] FastMM4BCB.cpp(2026): 
assigning to 
'ReallocMemFunc' (aka 'void *(*)(void *, int) __attribute__((fastcall))') 
from incompatible type 'void *(*)(void *, NativeInt) __attribute__((fastcall))': 
type mismatch at 2nd parameter ('int' vs 'NativeInt' (aka 'long long'))
```

However, I got rid of these by disabling the option `DetectMMOperationsAfterUninstall` in the `FastMM4Options.inc` file. But this shouldn't really be necessary?

When I then got it to compile and I could run my application I get a popup that states that "FastMM4 cannot be installed since another third party memory manager has already installed itself."

I have tried to google why this happens, but all I find is that I need to uncheck the use of dynamic RTL, I need to pragma link `FastMM4BCB.cpp` before any use of `USEFORM` and `FastMM4.pas` needs to be the first unit in the project. I think I have done this already. Can you provide me with any clues to why this popup shows up?

Comment: What version of FastMM are you using? The latest is 4.991. The author is not a C++ user, so fixes to `FastMM4BCB.cpp` usually come from the FastMM community. But  if you are getting the "Incompatible type" errors in the latest version, make sure to file a bug report at https://fastmm.sourceforge.net

Comment: The errors are because FastMM declares `GetMemFunc` and `ReallocMemFunc` (and `AllocMemFunc`) incorrectly on lines 160 and 162 (and 165). They need to take `NativeInt` parameters instead of `int` (and `unsigned`) parameters in C++Builder XE3+.  I created a bug report for that: https://sourceforge.net/p/fastmm/bugs/67/

Comment: As for the popup, I would suggest disabling FastMM and then query the currently installed memory manager at runtime to find out what it actually is. See `GetMemoryManager()` in `System.hpp`, and use the debugger to find out which module the function pointers are pointing into. If they are not pointing at the RTL's own `Sys...` functions in `System.hpp` (`SysGetMem`, `SysReallocMem`, etc), then there really is another memory manager being installed.

Comment: I am indeed using version 4.991. I did what you suggested and compared function pointers obtained with GetMemoryManager() and the pointers to the RTL memory functions. They are not the same, so that probably means that there is some other memory manager.

Comment: forgot to mention, there is also a `IsMemoryManagerSet()` function in `System.hpp` that does the same function pointer check to report if a 3rd party memory manager is installed.